# ssh fails to auth by public key (periodically)

Tags: 11.10, ssh

After an upgrade of desktop and server (both) to Ubuntu 11.10,  periodically the desktop is unable to perform publickey authentication with the server (-v option reveals nothing of evidently use).  Using the same key from pre-11.10 and Windows partitions is successful.

"Any ideas what gives?"  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*NOTE:*  I'm getting comment notifications for the Q above but it looks like they're not being posted.  Bug in the migration of the question?

In my case,  this was some kind of routing error when using a domain name to ssh to the server (which was at Amazon).   ssh -vvv revealed that we were being routed to another IP for some reason (I suspect AWS's internal DNS).  ssh-ing to the direct IP address of the server resolved the issue.